# If $F(x, y, z)=0$ find $ \frac {\delta z}{\delta x} , \frac {\delta z}{\delta y}$

Tags: partial-derivative

If $F(x, y, z)=0$ find $ \frac {\delta z}{\delta x} , \frac {\delta z}{\delta y}$

We can assume that x is represented as a function of y and z (since F is an implicit function), so y and z are independent.

to find $\frac {\delta z}{\delta x}$ do we need to show all possibilities like:

case 1: x is a function of y and z

case 2: y is a function of x and z

case 3: z is a function of x and y

Edit:

Consider z as a function of x and y,

$\frac {\delta F}{\delta x}$ = $\frac {\delta F}{\delta x}\frac {\delta x}{\delta x}$ + $\frac {\delta F}{\delta y}\frac {\delta y}{\delta x}$ + $\frac {\delta F}{\delta z}\frac {\delta z}{\delta x}$

Here $\frac {\delta y}{\delta x}$  will be zero since x and y are independent.

So,
$\frac {\delta F}{\delta x}$ = $\frac {\delta F}{\delta x}$ + $\frac {\delta F}{\delta z}\frac {\delta z}{\delta x}$

I am stuck here. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are taking the derivative of z with respect to x and with respect to y. So you are assuming that z is a function of x and y.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks @Aaron

Comment: @Aaron can you help me in finding dz/dx as i am stuck in expansion part

Comment: It looks like what you have is right.  Now solve algebraically for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$